# Intellij shorthand for html tags

Tags: html, intellij-idea

Is there a shorthand in Intellij idea for HTML tags?
I would like to HTML tags to be inferred from the shorthand. 
Also, are there any other shorthands Intellij for any other supported languages? (Please tag the question with those languages after answering)

Comment: It's **[Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)**; IntelliJ just supported it.

Comment: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41105802/2650174)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[Emmet](http://emmet.io/)** , IntelliJ supports it.

Check Emmet [Cheat Sheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) for quick start.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! `taga.classb#idc` followed by a tab expands to

```
 <taga class = "classb" id = "idc"> </tag>
```